# Can I restore my rank level back to where it was before a hacked Modern Warfare 2 server changed it?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I ended up in a hacked server. One of the hacks was - if you die by your own hand (such as falling off a skyscraper in my case) your rank (at your current prestige level) becomes 70.

While this is advantagous in that it partially unlocked things I wanted (ninja pro, claymores) so that I could earn them.   It means that a) I'm not earning xp as I play and b) I am level 70 without things fully unlocked.

(When I refer to 'partially' and 'fully' I mean that a partially unlocked thing means I still have to complete a challenge to get it, but it is 'unlocked' for my level.  Fully unlocked means I have it.  I can use it)

Is there a way to restore my account back to where it was (about level 15 third prestige)

Comment: The only way I can think of is by joining another hacked server that fixes it...

Comment: That was what I was thinking.  I'm guessing the hacked server would have to know what my rank was :).   I reckon it's a lost cause but figured there's nothing lost by asking the question.   I think I'll enjoy the level 70 for a bit and then start again on the next prestige level.  edit:  I use the word 'enjoy' rather loosely, as these days it is very very difficult to 'enjoy' this game unless you are a professional hard-core try-hard ruthless killing machine.

Comment: ... or a hacker ;)

Comment: or a hacker, yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just one thing...if you are running on OS that back-ups your files you can roll-back to a date prior to the hacked lobby.

My account was hacked too, i tried everything on the steam forums and the only thing that did work was going back to level 1, no prestige. Unfortunately i ticked off back-up.

I'm sorry that you had to work on your 3rd prestige and be hacked.

---

**EDIT**: if you want to try something look at the solutions posted here: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1297234

I've tried most of them but as i said they didn't work out, except the one where i could go back to level 1 without reinstalling my copy of MW2.