# How to reset all achievements and stats on Modern Warfare 2?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Recently, I joined a game in MW2 on PC and a weird meter bar came up on the screen.  Ten seconds later, I was cheerfully notified that all my achievements and prestiges etc had been unlocked for me, which made me very sad, because I've been trying to do them all myself.

So, is there a way to reset **all** my play statistics so that I can actually try to do them all myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A hacked Modern Warfare 2 server made my rank level 70. Can I undo it?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/a-hacked-modern-warfare-2-server-made-my-rank-level-70-can-i-undo-it)

Comment: It's the same issue, your account got hacked, i've edited my post to include a "possible" working alternative to going back to level 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Ensure Steam is running, delete all the files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\nnnnnnnnn\10190\remote` and all the `stat` files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\call of duty modern warfare 2\players`.

Comment: That won't work. They will be redownloaded from Steam Cloud the next time you start/end the game.

Comment: I think this works if you zero out the files and save them because it syncs the most recent edit.  Just a hunch.

Comment: @Bora It definitely will work; I just verified as much myself. Simply deleting them while Steam is running will suffice.

Comment: I was then able to restore my true rank by deleting the newly created files and moving the old files back to their proper location.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is contacting Steam Account Support and requesting a stats reset.

Now this is not the usual practice, and they are not obliged to do this upon request, but they will help, if you ask friendly. On one occasion I wrote them to reset my achievement progress on Portal because I was stuck getting an achievement, which they did silently.

Again, this is inofficial. Just say the magic word ;)

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is not correct. There are other ways of achieving this without having to wait for the intervention of support staff.

Comment: Ah, saw your other posts. Might come in handy later on, then :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get your stats zeroed out is to start a whole new character with a new gamertag.

For xbox players with the same question about resetting your stats to get a better K/D or accuracy stat: There is no way to reset your achievements or stats. However, when you enter Prestige modes, after reaching Level 70 (Prestige 0) you completely hard boot your character. You lose all of your perks, killstreaks, deathstreaks, guns, everything. You begin earning them again as if you just started playing Multiplayer, except you already have stats. Also, once you are one of the 10 levels of prestige, you have a more covetted icon next to your name.

Comment: You can't really do that with the PC version.  The game is registered to your Steam account; changing accounts involves creating a new account then buying another copy of the game with it...